# Distributing AND over OR in a binary tree (Conjunctive Normal Form)

Tags: java, recursion, logic, binary-tree

I'm trying to convert a binary tree e.g.

```
OR (Implementation of Operator - a specialisation of TreeNode... see below)
|-A (Implementation of TreeNode... see below)
|-OR
  |-B
  |-AND (Implementation of Operator - a specialisation of TreeNode... see below)
    |-C
    |-OR
      |-D
      |-E
```

into it's equivalent Conjunctive Normal Form (CND) representation. I believe that because I'm only using the logical OR + AND operators that the only step I'd have to perform is the distribution of AND over OR. This would produce the following tree (still binary for my purposes) in CNF:

```
AND
|-OR
| |-A
| |-OR
|   |-B
|   |-OR
|     |-E
|     |-D
|-OR
  |-A
  |-OR
    |-B
    |-OR
      |-E
      |-C
```

I'm having issues creating an algorithm to do this... so far I have the following skeleton which will re-write the tree bottom up (Notice the recursive call to reconstruct):

```
public TreeNode reconstruct(TreeNode treeNode) {
  if(treeNode instanceof Operator) {
    TreeNode left = reconstruct(((Operator)treeNode).getLeft());
    TreeNode right = reconstruct(((Operator)treeNode).getRight());

    return distribute(treeNode, left, right);
  }
  else
    return node;
}
```

Using classes:

```
 -----------
|  TreeNode | // Interface
 -----------
      ^
      |
 -----------
| Operator  | // Interface
 -----------
| getLeft() |
| getRight()|
| setLeft() |
| setRight()|
 -----------
```

Could anybody suggest an implementation of distribute which would convert to CNF?

// EDIT 1 (After answer from nif)

```
private Node distribute(TreeNode node, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
  if (node instanceof Or) {
    if (left instanceof And) {
      // distribute right over left AND
      return 
        new And(
          new Or(((Operator)left).getLeft(), right),
          new Or(((Operator)left).getRight(), right)
        );
    } 
    else if (right instanceof And) {
      // distribute left over right AND
      return 
        new And(
          new Or(((Operator)right).getLeft(), left),
          new Or(((Operator)right).getRight(), left)
        );
    }
  }
  if(node instanceof Operator) {
    ((Operator)node).setLeft(left);
    ((Operator)node).setRight(right);
  }
  // default
  return node;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AND` and `OR` are the only operators you are using, it shouldn't be hard to tranform your tree to CNF. All you have to do is find structures in the form `OR(AND(X,Y), Z)` or `OR(Z, AND(X,Y))` and use the distribution law.

```
private static TreeNode distribute(TreeNode n, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
  if (n instanceof Or) {
    if (left instanceof And) {
      // distribute right over left AND
      return new And(new Or(left.getLeft(), right), 
                     new Or(left.getRight(), right));
    } else if (right instanceof And) {
      // distribute left over right AND
      return new And(new Or(right.getLeft(), left), 
                     new Or(right.getRight(), left));
    }
  }

  // no change
  return treeNode;
}
```

This algorithm must be applied to all nodes of your tree until the tree isn't changed anymore. The order in which you apply the algorithm to the nodes doesn't matter. Intuitively, repetitive application of the algorithm will *pull up* all `AND` nodes over `OR` nodes until the tree is in CNF.

```
TreeNode root = ....;
while (true) {
  TreeNode transformedRoot = reconstruct(root);
  if (root.equals(transformedRoot)) {
    break;
  }
  root = transformedRoot;
}
// root is now in CNF
```

**Note:** Be aware that the CNF transformation may blow up your tree exponential in size. The shown implementation is quite primitive and doesn't use any enhancements to reduce computation time.

Comment: Thanks... I had not considered an iterative approach therefore my implementation of the distribute method was a lot more involved and complex, this is a lot simpler! One thing I did have to do was to introduce a small block of code to the distribute method for a default return so that the left and right hand side of the TreeNode were set before return however still a great answer! I've included the altered code in an edit of the original question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look how the tree is navigated, in your code looks like is a Depth-first search so you will start with the deepest branch (Deepest operator) you have to design your method `distribute` expecting that order and apply the Distributive Laws for the child nodes in a backtracking way.

A very general description of what distribute method should do is:

> The flow of what kind of distributive law have to be applied depends
>   on parent's operation type and child nodes.
>       Each child node can be an operator or a  value, depending on this combination do the distribution required by the law.

A pseudo code of what i am trying to tell you is:

```
if parent node is OR type
    if child nodes are OPERATOR-VALUE combination
        if OPERATION is AND type
            apply correspondig distribution 
            return the new parent
        else
            apply correspondig distribution 
            return the new parent
    if child node are VALUE-VALUE combination
        return parent
if parent node is AND type
    if child nodes are OPERATOR-VALUE combination
        if OPERATION is AND type
            apply correspondig distribution 
            return the new parent
        else
            apply correspondig distribution 
            return the new parent
    if child nodes are VALUE-VALUE combination
        return parent;
```

An implementation example:

```
public TreeNode distribute(TreeNode parent,TreeNode leftChild, TreeNode rightChild) {
    if( !(leftChild instanceof Operator) && !(rightChild instanceof Operator) ){
        /*There is nothing to do */
        return parent;
    }
    if( parent.getType() == 'OR'){
        /*
            Apply distributive laws and return the new branch
            for example:        
        */
        if ( (leftChild instanceof operator) &&  !(rightChild instanceof Operator) ){
            TreeNode operatorLeftChild  = leftChild.getLeftChild();
            TreeNode operatorRightChild = leftChild.getRightChild();
            if(leftChild.getType() == 'AND' )
            {
                /*
                Applying distributive laws:
                    rightChild OR (operatorLeftChild AND operatorRightChild) 
                        -> (rightChild OR operatorLeftChild) AND (rightChild OR operatorRightChild)
                */
                TreeNode newBranch = new Operator("AND");
                /*new Left child*/
                TreeNode newLeftChild= new Operator("OR");
                newLeftChild.setLeftChild(rightChild);
                newLeftChild.setRightChild(operatorLeftChild);
                /*new Richt Child */
                TreeNode newRightChild= new Operator("OR");
                newRightChild.setLeftChild(rightChild);
                newRightChild.setRightChild(operatorRightChild);
                /*Setting the new Branch*/
                newBranch.setLeftChild(newLeftChild);
                newBranch.setRightChild(newRightChild);
                return newBranch;
            }

        }
    }
    if( parent.getType() == 'AND'){
        /*
            Else-If and distributive laws stuff
        */
    }
    /*
        You can also implement this part wihtout the else-if code by implementing a true table
        but is more abstract and less human redeable
     */
}
```

**Note** The previous code has not been tested and  i am assuming a lot of things i dont know
how your tree is implemented may be you will be required to update the parent reference in child nodes.