# Can a conjunctive/disjunctive normal form be represented in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, automata, conjunctive-normal-form

I could find this relative question
[Distributing AND over OR in a binary tree (Conjunctive Normal Form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238768/distributing-and-over-or-in-a-binary-tree-conjunctive-normal-form)

I'm not quite sure what would be the out come of the CNF binary tree representation for the this expression.
A & B & C

```
AND
|- A
|- AND
   |-B
   |-C
```

Is this right? My basic question is does the CNF binary representation can have multiple AND nodes in the tree rather than just one AND node as root. My understanding is we could have non-root AND nodes as long as its parent is an AND node.

Related question is? Is this representation optimal? or representing them in a n-nary tree with just one root AND node is beneficial? The optimality I'm looking here is wrt building and traversal of the tree.

// Edit based on the comment.
For the sake of simplicity, assume that the `not (~)` operator is part of leaf nodes A, B or C. That means you need to worry about ~ operator being part of the non-leaf nodes which might change the tree structure when expanded as per Demorgan's law.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the tree. Binary trees make sense for search trees, because at each node, your key is either less than (recurse left), equal to (stop), or greater than (recurse right) the key in the current node. This makes for the most easily implemented trees, but other types of search trees (B-trees, for one) use higher degrees of branching to optimize for things like cache usage. Here, there doesn't seem to be anything inherently "binary" about CNF, so I would use an n-ary tree unless it causes a noticeable problem.

Comment: @Adi GuN CNF/DNF **cannot** be expressed via binary trees, as it includes ``Not``, which is a unary operator. Besides that, any expression composed from binary operators - including but not limited to CNF/DNF - **can** be express via binary trees. It's a question of the arity of the operators, not a question of the form at all.

Comment: @AmiTavory I've updated the description. For the sake of simplicity not is already drilled down to the leaf nodes.

Comment: @Ami CNF/DNF can be represented as Binary Decision Diagrams, because BDDs can forward 0 as well as 1.

Comment: @Alex Kemper That might be true, but the question seems to be about expression trees with operator internal nodes, not BDDs (where variables can be also internal nodes).

Answer (score 0):

A minimum [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) for your conjunction:

[image]

The [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) was created using this [online tool](http://formal.cs.utah.edu:8080/pbl/BDD.php).

For a simple `AND` with three inputs, there is nothing to optimize. The [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) nodes build a chain.

Comment: Though this is interesting, I'd really like the operators to flow through the tree.

Comment: A BDD can be thought as a 2-to-1 multiplexer tree.